# Batch Script fails in IF statement

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

My batch script is failing in the second `if` state of `:nbig`. (I have found this out using `@echo` after each statement). However, the `SET` statement within the `if` succeed if run normally, as does the `if` statement with an `@echo` inside. This is very peculiar and I can't see what I have done wrong.

My code is here:

```
:: Set the day and night values
set /A nighttemp = 2700
set /A daytemp = 6500
:: Set Transition Duration 
set /A transitionduration = 60
:: Set times in minutes from midnight
set /A tnight = 1380
set /A tday = 480

For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/:." %%a in ("%TIME%") do (
    SET /A HH24=%%a
    SET /A MI=%%b
    SET /A SS=%%c
    SET /A FF=%%d
)

SET /A mins = %HH24%*60 + %MI%
SET /A tdaywindow = %tday% + 60
SET /A tnightwindow = %tnight% + 60

if %tnight% GEQ %tday% ( GOTO NBIG) 
if %tnight% LSS %tday% ( GOTO DBIG)

pause

:NBIG

if %mins% LSS %tday% ( SET /A temp = %nighttemp% )
if %mins% LSS %tdaywindow% ( SET /A temp = (%daytemp% - %nighttemp%)*((%mins% - %tday%)/60) + %nighttemp% )
if %mins% LSS %tnight%( SET /A temp = %daytemp% )
if %mins% LSS %tnightwindow%( SET /A temp =  (%nighttemp% - %daytemp%)*((%mins% - %tnight%)/60) + %daytemp% )
GOTO ENDING

:DBIG
if %mins% LSS %tnight%( SET /A temp = %daytemp% )
if %mins% LSS %tnightwindow% ( SET /A temp = (%nighttemp% - %daytemp%)*((%mins% - %tnight%)/60) + %daytemp%)
if %mins% LSS %tday% ( SET /A temp = %nighttemp% )
if %mins% LSS %tdaywindow% ( SET /A temp = (%daytemp% - %nighttemp%)*((%mins% - %tday%)/60) + %nighttemp% )
GOTO ENDING

:ENDING
@echo %temp%
pause

::%~dp0\redshift.exe -O %temp%
```

A correctly running program should `@echo` the value of `temp`, however it errors.

(Aside: This is to run the redshift program with custom times...)

Comment: Please read the Stack Overflow documentation page [Variables in Batch Files](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/3528/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The batch parser must parse the open and close parentheses before SET /A command, so a closing paren within SET /A is being applied to the opening paren *before* SET /A.

You would either need to escape the closing parens within the computation

```
if %mins% LSS %tdaywindow% ( SET /A temp = (%daytemp% - %nighttemp%^)*((%mins% - %tday%^)/60^) + %nighttemp% )
```

or better yet, enclose the entire assignment within quotes:

```
if %mins% LSS %tdaywindow% ( SET /A "temp = (%daytemp% - %nighttemp%)*((%mins% - %tday%)/60) + %nighttemp%" )
```

But perhaps the simplest solution is to ditch the outer parens entirely - they are not needed with the way you have structured your code.

```
if %mins% LSS %tdaywindow% SET /A "temp = (%daytemp% - %nighttemp%)*((%mins% - %tday%)/60) + %nighttemp%"
```

Even though they are not needed with this last form, I still like to enclose my SET assignment within quotes.

Unrelated to your error, you can further simplify your code by using the SET /A feature that automatically expands numeric variables without needing `%` or `!` (only available to SET /A)

```
if %mins% LSS %tdaywindow% SET /A "temp = (daytemp - nighttemp)*((mins - tday)/60) + nighttemp"
```